# Many to many relationship - Get all objects linked to other one

Tags: c#, telerik-open-access

I have two classes:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Groups = new List<Group>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        this.Users = new List<User>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined a many-to-many relationship with OpenAccess by using a join table:

```
mapping.HasAssociation(user => user.Groups).WithOpposite(group => group.Users).MapJoinTable("UserGroup", (user, group) => new
            {
                UserId = user.Id,
                GroupId = group.Id
            });
```

I would like to get all users who are associated to the group x.

How to write the linq request ?

I finally want to remove the group x after removing of all links (user/group) to this group. Or is it possible to make it automatically by a cascade delete ? I am interesting by the two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can select `Users` from `Group` using sample code below

```
var allUserInGroup = Group.Where(group => group.Id == id).Select(group => group.Users).ToList();
```

For the delete part:

```
if(!group.Any(g => g.Users))  {  // assume group is IQueryable/IEnumerable
   context.Group.Remove(group);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The selection gives me a trackedList[User]. How to use it in a loop ? How to convert it to a IEnumerable (List for example) ?

Comment: I have an error "Unknown method Any(?)" with the delete part.

Comment: @profou: I edited my answer. You just call `ToList()` in the first part. The second part, the group must be IEnumerable or IQueryable